# Asus N55SF dual monitor setup

Tags: multiple-monitors, nvidia-optimus

I am a new user of ubuntu.

I wanted to plug my 24 inch Samsung monitor to my laptop with HDMI.

My laptop has an Nvidia GT 555M and an i7 sandy bridge. so i have 2 graphic cards.

But when i go to displays it said there is only one display (the one from my laptop).

I have tried several things, I have installed Bumblebee but I do not know how to use it.

I only know about `optirun` for using the Nvidia card.

Comment: i mean. so i have 2 graphic card  because i7 sany bridge has intel HD2000 graphis onboard

Comment: i found something intresting.  when i use optirun for running steam . my monitor gives me information that it had connection.

Comment: There are still issues to work out with optimus, like what David Airlie calls "reverse optimus" to make HDMI and other video outputs work straight from the nVidia card: http://airlied.livejournal.com/76723.html

Please join this team (https://launchpad.net/~hybrid-graphics-linux) if you are new by clicking on the "Join Team" link at the right of the Launchpad page. It's important to have as many users in the community as possible to request for appropriate support, even if you found a non-obvious way to make it work for you.